# How to put the onchange event of a select list?

Tags: jquery, selectlist

I am ready with my next problem. I have a select list which is populated as follows:

```
<select id= "tables" name= "tables">
    <option value="select">-- Select --</option>
    <option value = student> Student</option>
    <option value = teachers > Teachers </option>
    //etc..
</select>
```

On the onchange event of the select list another select list is populated.

My first problem is when I select an item, say "Student", the view still remains on the "Select" option.I want that it should show the item I select.

My second query is, if I do not write "-- Select --" and "Student is the first item" then when I click Student for the first time nothing happens means the 2nd selct list doesnot get populated.

Please help!

Comment: Can you show some sample code

Comment: Are you submitting the form on onchange event?

Comment: No jai.I am just calling a backend method on the onchange event which is populating the 2nd list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your html is like that :

```
<select id= "tables" name= "tables">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option><!-- setting the value to none -->
    <option value = student> Student</option> 
    <option value = teachers > Teachers </option>
</select>
```

With jQuery, it'll be the `change` event :

```
$('#tables').on('change', function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value.length != 0) {
        alert(value);
    }

});
```

[See a live example there](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/M9t22/2/).

Comment: That's a very long way of getting the selected value... `:)`

Comment: By the way, ommiting quotes is perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: gordon,can you give me a shorter way.

Comment: thanks a lot soyuka.this answers my 1st query. Canyou help me with my 2nd problem?

Comment: @Trisha What did, my comment or my answer ? Can you try making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example of what you're trying to do ?

Comment: your answer. Ok soyuka, I have edited your jsfiddle.If you notice,I have just removed the option select.but now when I am selecting the items its not working.How can that work.

Comment: sorry soyuka.I didn't update thats why it was not working.silly mistake.now its working.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On change event

```
$('#tables').change(function(){
    alert('change: ' + $(this).val())
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nXKC7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

IS this what you want, [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/M9t22/6/)

HTML CODE

```
<select id= "tables" name= "tables">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option><!-- setting the value to none -->
    <option value = "student"> Student</option>
    <option value =" teachers" > Teachers </option>
</select>

<select id= "tables2" name= "tables">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value = student> Student</option>
    <option value = teachers > Teachers </option>
    //etc..
</select>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
$(function(){
    $('#tables').on('change', function(e) {
        $('#tables2').val(this.value);
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks rajesh but i have already done the population of the 2nd list.May be you didn't understand my problem.Its a bit peculiar.When I am clicking Student normally in the 1st select list the name Student should show but its showing Select.

Comment: you should check your source what your select is generated what value does student label have

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
   $('#tables').change(function(){
     var selectedVal = $(this).val();
     alert(selectedVal);
   })
```